# Why this Rust code allocates buffers on same memory region?

Tags: memory, rust, embedded, rtos

I don't understand the behaviour of this piece of code... I'm writing an RTOS an this issue is halting me. I really don't get why the code acts this way.

Here is some code I tested on the playground that shows the issue.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc6cc0ec8bfe76f65e1baaa67caaf9e6

```rust
use core::fmt;
use core::fmt::Display;

struct StackPointer(*const usize);

impl Display for StackPointer {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0 as usize)
    }
}

struct Stack<const WORDS: usize> {
    pub sp: StackPointer,
    pub mem: [usize; WORDS],
}

impl<const WORDS: usize> Stack<WORDS> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mem = [0; WORDS];
        let sp = StackPointer(mem.as_ptr() as *const usize);
        
        Self {
            mem,
            sp,
        }
    }
}


struct PCB<const WORDS: usize> {
    pub stack: Stack<WORDS>,
}

impl<const WORDS: usize> PCB<WORDS> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            stack: Stack::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pcb1 = PCB::<128>::new();
    let pcb2 = PCB::<128>::new();
    let pcb3 = PCB::<128>::new();
    
    println!("sp1: {}, sp2: {}, sp3: {}", pcb1.stack.sp, pcb2.stack.sp, pcb3.stack.sp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand the behaviour of this piece of code... I'm writing an RTOS an this issue is halting me. I really don't get why the code acts this way.

Because you're writing broken code.

```rust
let mem = [0; WORDS];
```

this reserves WORDS words on the stack (incidentally why is it `usize`?)

```rust
let sp = StackPointer(mem.as_ptr() as *const usize);
```

this takes a pointer to a location in the current stackframe, where you've put your array.

```rust
Self {
    mem,
    sp,
}
```

this then blissfully copies the data out of the current stackframe and into the parent stackframe, while keeping a pointer to the now-popped stackframe.

So on each call to `PCB::<128>::new();` you're going to create a stackframe, allocate an array into that stackframe, take a pointer to that array (in the stackframe), then pop the stackframe.

All the stackframes being in the same location (on top of `main`'s stackframe) they're at roughly the same offset, hence the array is at the same offset in all calls, and all your nonsensical `StackPointer` store data to the same location, which will be filled with nonsense as soon as you call an other function.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I thought I was moving the buffer out of the function, leaving memory allocated there, but I was wrong. 
Before I was globally allocating the stacks (using static muts) and that worked; I wanted to eliminate that, but maybe is the right way to do it. Thank you a lot!